# Why is moving return to the end of the function less efficient?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

**EDIT: After removing the UB (good spot, I missed it), the times are more or less identical. Will flag a moderator to delete it.**

These two functions are identical except for the fact that `foo` has the return inside the `if`, on both branches, whereas `goo` has a single `return` at the end:

```
int foo()
{
    static int x = 0;
    if ( x )
    {
        x > 2 ? x = 0 : ++x;
        return x-1;
    }
    else
    {
        x++;
        return x-1;
    }
}
int goo()
{
    static int x = 0;
    if ( x )
    {
        x > 2 ? x = 0 : ++x;
    }
    else
    {
        x++;
    }
    return x-1;
}
```

The numbers are there just so optimizations don't kick in too hard and the function call isn't optimized away. Compiled with **full optimization** on MSVS 2010.

Calling the function 4000000000 times, sampled 10 times, `foo` was **always** faster:

- `foo` - **8830 ms** average
- `goo` - **8703 ms** average

The difference is small, but it's there. Why? Also, why doesn't the compiler optimize them to the same thing?

Comment: Have you checked the assembler output?

Comment: @larsmans yes, the function are inlined and the first one is *larger* (although it takes less). I'm also looking into reasons **why** the compiler doesn't see whatever optimizations it's doing for one of them.

Comment: Did you look at the ASM code that was produced?

Comment: You are writting code to bother the optimizer, and then you wonder about the differences? If you care to understand your particular example, read the generated assembly, but note that this might not reflect at all what would happen in any other function.

Comment: And btw., what should the `++x` in `x = x > 2 ? 0 : ++x` do? I'm not being pedantic; I really don't know what the expected behavior of that expression is and whether it may interfere with the optimizer.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'm only bothering it enough to prove a point.

Comment: I think there should be additional `jmp`, check asm output.

Comment: @larsmans just increments x. In the test I wrote, I would sum up the return values, so I needed to guard against overflows (ergo the `x-1` and resetting x to 0).

Comment: @larsmans: Good point, that expression is undefined behavior.

Comment: @larsmans agreed with david, it's UB.

Comment: `x = x > 2 ? 0 : ++x;`  invokes Undefined behavior.

Comment: What I find amazing since I still remember VAXes and MIPs, is that you are doing an average of one call (even if inlined) per 2<μS.  Also the first inline variant emits extra statements (albeit branched over) and has an extra branch target.  This could easily perturb the instruction fetch and caching enough to create this 5% difference.

Comment: It really isn't worth much to ask why a certain compiler misses some optimization opportunity. After all, they are not all claiming to be able to emit the overall best code. Try using the gcc explorer to see how gcc and clang do it, and you will see they both make no difference.

Comment: @larsmans the UB fix changed everything.

Comment: @Nawaz yes, and fixing it reduced the time difference to non-noticeable.

Comment: I think `x = x > 2 ? 0 : ++x;` is well defined in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the assembler output, there might be a jump to the end of the function in the first branch of goo().

Comment: Yes but that first branch is never taken.

Comment: I'm thinking it has something to do with branch prediction and pipelining.

Comment: @TerryE x is static, so it is incremented in the second brunch and thus the first branch is called in a next function call.

Comment: @TorstenRobitzki, yup, I also realised that after posting the comment, but too late to edit it :oops: -- Mindfart

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that it's because having the return in every `if` , the moment the operation is done, `foo` will return the calculated variable.

`goo`, even thought it does the same thing, except for the two returns, will still have to check the `else` statement.That uses some time  (extremely small) but as you can see, it is mesurable.

Comment: What do you mean it still has to check the `else` statement?

Comment: I don't think the else needs to be checked.  First, there is no "checking" an else.  Else is true if everything before it was false.  Also, if the `if` condition is true, the `else` block never runs, so I don't see any difference in work.  Like the others said, the assembly code may be different.

Answer (score -3):

In case of foo end braces of "if" and "else" will not be executed. After the return

statement the control will got o the end brace of function directly.

Thats why it will take less time for foo.

Comment: Naren, a core doesn't execute "braces".  It executes instructions.  However you are right in a way in that some compilers align branch targets on 4/8 byte boundaries to help improve instruction caching, and having an extra target as well as the extra code for the first `return x+1` could effect the timing.

Comment: I know this is not executed, but I tried this by giving break points and the execution went directly to the end brace of function....
You also try with break point and check.